# Как ускорить запуск Ubuntu 18.04? [closed]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Вот, что запускается при загрузке. Можно ли  что-то отключить и что можно оптимизировать?

Comment: Можно как вариант выбрать минимальную установку, когда устанавливается система, а необходимое уже доставить.

Comment: Тут только мнения, мнения... Не известно, что используется пользователем, а что нет. Gnome3 сразу в топку, лучше поставить более легкую оболочку: Xfce, Mate, Cinnamon, Lxde (на выбор)

Comment: [Увеличение скорости работы Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/ubuntu_optimization) - думаю этого достаточно, если будет мало - менять дистрибутив

Comment: Также [вот это в помощь](https://greatech.ru/2018/08/06/how-to-speed-up-ubuntu-1804/)

Comment: Поменяй HDD на SSD.